# How to Unlock Applications folder

Tags: authentication

This question relates to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I wish to move a folder from the desktop into the applications folder at `/home/usr/share/applications`.  When I attempt to drag the folder from the desktop to the applications folder, I get the following message:

"Error moving file: Permission denied"

Permission or no permission, I want to move a folder from the desktop to the above said applications folder.  How do I authenticate so I can make this move?  There is no opportunity to authenticate when I get the error message, only "Skip" or "Cancel".  I don't want to skip or cancel, I want to authenticate and move the folder.  How do I do this?

On top of things, when I try to use PCmanFM and attempt to open the applications folder as Root, I get the error message: "Switch User Command Not Set". What do I do now?  Thanx!

Comment: You meant the directory at `/usr/share/applications`? `home/usr` is not a known path.

Comment: `sudo cp -Ri ~/Desktop/foldername /usr/share/applications/`.This command is for copying,after copied you can delete the folder in destop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be root to do this because the permissions are obviously set so.

First solution:

Try to find a "Open current Folder as root" in your file managers menu bar. I use PCManFM, and in that case it is under "Tools -> Open current Folder as root". After that just copy files as you wish.

Second solution:

Open terminal the terminal and type `sudo cp -R /path/of/source /path/of/destionation`. Use the -R option if you want to copy a folder, you don't need it for regular files. After you hit Enter, type your password and that's it.